# How to increase the height/size of the results/match window for the vim ctrlp plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctrlp

With the vim [ctrlp (control-p) plugin](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim), when I execute the `control+p` command to search for files, the window showing the results is at most 10 lines high.  How can I make it bigger, and take up my entire window so I can see more results at a time?

[image: screenshot showing results window limited to 10 lines]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `max` value for the `ctrlp_match_window` (in your vim session or in your .vimrc file), e.g.,

`:let g:ctrlp_match_window = 'min:4,max:999'`

[image: screenshot showing setting the variable]
[image: screenshot showing the results taking up the whole window]

Per `:help g:ctrlp_match_window` :

> *'g:ctrlp_match_window'*
>
> Change the position, the listing order of results, the minimum and the maximum heights of the match window:
>   ...
>
> The minimum and maximum heights:
>     min:{n} - show minimum {n} lines (default: 1).
>     max:{n} - show maximum {n} lines (default: 10).
>
> The maximum number of results:
>     results:{n} - list maximum {n} results (default: sync with max height).

See also: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/187#issuecomment-44924110

Comment: Thx, your example is the behavior I wanted!